# org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.com/<project name>: cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: jgit

I am trying to "list remote branches/tags without a local repository". I am using jgit for this. The code snippet is as follows:

```
     try {
          Git.lsRemoteRepository()
              .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password"))
              .setRemote("https://gitlab.com/<projectname>").call();
          System.out.println("validatation successfull");
        }
        catch (GitAPIException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
```

The code works fine when I run in eclipse as java program. But when I build a jar and try to run that in command line I get TransportException.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.com/<projectname>: cannot open git-upload-pack
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:161)
        at com.bosch.rtc.git.sync.main.GitLabTest.main(GitLabTest.java:25)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.com/<Projectname>: cannot open git-upload-pack
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:626)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:200)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gitlab.com
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:289)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1232)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
        at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.JDKHttpConnection.getResponseCode(JDKHttpConnection.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:540)
        ... 4 more
https://gitlab.com/<projectname>.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
```

Comment: There is not much to see without the details of the exception, so please add it so others can take a closer look.

Comment: I have appended the complete exception message.

Comment: Did you try to specify a proper URL instead of "<projectname>"?